# Scriptprocessing doesnt stop after -ErrorAction stop

Tags: windows, powershell, error-handling

I am writing a script where I have written in and call some own functions. The first function I call is my logging setup function where I set up the log file like this:

```
function Create-Logfile {
    if (!(Test-Path $Path)) { 

        try {
            Write-Verbose "Write-Log: Creating $Path" 
            $NewLogFile = New-Item $Path -Force -ItemType File -ErrorAction stop
        } catch {
            Write-Verbose "Write-Log: Creating $Path failed: $($error[0].Exception.Message)" 
        }

    } 

    write-host 'i do still execute'
}

function Do-Something{
    write-host 'doing something'
}

Create-LogFile #create the file
write-host 'processing didnt stop'
Do-Something
```

If the file cannot be created I want the whole following script processing to stop, but all following calls are still processed. Event other function calls do still execute :( If the log file creation failed I dont want anything to go on as the logfile is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are catching the terminating error in the try catch block, you will have to add a termination statement after your write-host command. There are several to choose from depending on your needs (e.g., exit, break, etc.).

Example:

```
try 
{
  Write-Verbose "Write-Log: Creating $Path" 
  $NewLogFile = New-Item $Path -Force -ItemType File -ErrorAction stop
} 
catch 
{
  Write-Verbose "Write-Log: Creating $Path failed: $($error[0].Exception.Message)"
  exit
}
```

Alternatively, you can throw your own terminating error like this:

```
throw "Write-Log: Creating $Path failed: $($error[0].Exception.Message)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethrow the error..

```
function Create-Logfile {
    if (!(Test-Path $Path)) { 

        try {
            Write-Verbose "Write-Log: Creating $Path" 
            $NewLogFile = New-Item $Path -Force -ItemType File -ErrorAction stop
        } catch {
            Write-Verbose "Write-Log: Creating $Path failed: $($error[0].Exception.Message)" 
           Throw
        }

    } 

    write-host 'i do still execute'
}

function Do-Something{
    write-host 'doing something'
}

Create-LogFile #create the file
write-host 'processing didnt stop'
Do-Something
```